# Validate Partial View in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, partial-views

I have been trying using `Data annonations` to validate `form` on my `partial view` which i am showing on `bootstrap modal dialog`. Following is code

**Partial View**

```
@model JoyRydeStoreWebPortal.Models.tbl_user

<div class="modal fade" id="createLoginModal" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <form class="modal-content" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index","Index", new{ Area = "Admin" })">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="createLoginTitle">Create Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modal => modal.TXT_USER_ID, new { placeholder = "UserID", id="userID" , @class="form-control"})                     
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 form-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modal => modal.TXT_USER_PWD, new {type="Password",  placeholder = "Password", id = "userPwd", @class = "form-control" })                        
                </div>                  
                <div class="col-sm-12 pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" type="submit">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Index View** where i am `rendering` partial view

```
@model List<JoyRydeStoreWebPortal.Models.tbl_store>
@using GridMvc.Html;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_layoutAdmin.cshtml";
}
<div class="page">
<div class="page-content padding-30 container-fluid">
       @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
       {
           columns.Add(foo => foo.LNG_STORE_ID,true).Sortable(true);
           columns.Add(foo => foo.TXT_STORE_NAME).Titled("Store Name").SetWidth(110).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
           columns.Add(foo => foo.TXT_STORE_CONTACT).Titled("Phone Number").SetWidth(110).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
           columns.Add() .Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="#createLoginModal" data-toggle="modal">Create Login</a>);
           columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth(30).RenderValueAs(o => @<a href="#">Detail</a>);
       }).WithPaging(20)
</div>
<div>
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial_CreateLogin", new JoyRydeStoreWebPortal.Models.tbl_user());}
</div>
```

Following is my Modal Class for `TBL_USER` create by `Entity Framework`

```
namespace JoyRydeStoreWebPortal.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(tbl_userMetaData))]
public partial class tbl_user
{
    public long LNG_USER_ID { get; set; }
    public string TXT_USER_ID { get; set; }
    public string TXT_USER_PWD { get; set; }
    public long LNG_STORE_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual tbl_store tbl_store { get; set; }
}
```

}

**tbl_userMetaData class**

```
public class tbl_userMetaData
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User ID is required")]
    public string TXT_USER_ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Password is required")]
    public string TXT_USER_PWD { get; set; }        
}
```

**Index Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (joyryde_storeEntities context = new joyryde_storeEntities())
        {

            var items = context.tbl_store.ToList();
            return View(items);               
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection frm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            RedirectToAction("Index", new { Area = "Admin" });
        }
        return View();

    }
```

Here `ModalState.IsValid` always return true. and modal dialog does not validate.

What causing the behaviour ?

Comment: Your POST method does not have a parameter for your model (just a parameter for `FormCollection` - which your should never use) so there are no `ModelState` errors

Comment: can u  please elaborate your answer. I am still new in MVC and learning it. I want if both fields are not validate, modal dialog should not be closed and show errors.

Comment: Your method needs to be `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Index(tbl_user model)`. And you will not get any validation in the client because you have not included any `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` associated with your properties

Answer (score 2):

Do not use FormCollection on your post

try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include="ITXT_USER_ID ,TXT_USER_PWD ")]tbl_userMetaData userMetaData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        RedirectToAction("Index", new { Area = "Admin" });
    }
    return View();

}
```

It is good practice to specify the properties to be binded.

Comment: It is showing `ModalState` invalid, but modal dialog close on post back of form.

Comment: It is not _good practice to specify the properties to be binded._ What is good practice is to use a view model so the `[Bind]` attribute is never required.